# Improving entity naming with custom file/code in NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

We've been working with the NLTK library in a recent project where we're 
mainly interested in the named entities part.

In general we're getting good results using the NEChunkParser class. 
However, we're trying to find a way to provide our own terms to the 
parser, without success.

For example, we have a test document where my name (Shay) appears in 
several places. The library finds me as GPE while I'd like it to find 
me as PERSON...

Is there a way to provide some kind of a custom file/ 
code so the parser will be able to interpret the named entity as I 
want it to?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Shay, did you make any progress on this? I'd love to see what you came up with because I'm going through a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution is to compile a list of entities that you know are misclassified, then filter the `NEChunkParser` output in a postprocessing module and replace these entities' tags with the tags you want them to have.

The proper solution is to retrain the NE tagger. If you look at the [source code](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chunk.named_entity-pysrc.html) for NLTK, you'll see that the `NEChunkParser` is based on a MaxEnt classifier, i.e. a machine learning algorithm. You'll have to compile and annotate a corpus (dataset) that is representative for the kind of data you want to work with, then retrain the NE tagger on this corpus. (This is hard, time-consuming and potentially expensive.)